# Getting better results on LSTM (Tensorflow) shaping timesteps into features (?)

Tags: lstm, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am building multiple models for several different environments (similar applications) with LSTMs on Tensorflow. I know and I have seen people commenting on how inappropriate it is to build LSTMs with a single timestep, but results speak for themselves.

In all of the cases, I find that if I shape data for LSTM the way it's meant to [sample size, timesteps, features], it takes a very long time for the model to train. On the other hand, if I formulate the problem as an MLP: that's placing all of the timesteps in the feature dimension (feature 1 t-5, feature 2 t-5..., feature 1 t-1...), and having a single timestep, the results are very similar for the same epochs, but the model trains much faster. I have also found that building the model the right way, flattens the learning curve (epoch vs loss) in the same way as the wrong way; so it´s not like I am missing on further epoch training.

Is this normal? Is there a high chance I am missing something? I did some online courses on LSTMs and keep constantly checking blogs and books on stuff, so even though I am an amateur, I have some knowledge.

Comment: How do you assess performance of the model?

Comment: For instance, the loss when training, but also MAE and scaled MAE.

Comment: You mean training loss and training metrics?

Comment: What is your data like?

Comment: Data is a time-sequence. That's what is surprising.